# pgAdmin on a fresh OS X Server installation

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, mac-os-x

I know for sure postgresql is running (checked with `ps ax`), but when I install pgAdmin and try to make a server connection to localhost I get this error:

```
Server doesn't listen
The server doesn't accept connections: the connection library reports 
could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "localhost" (fe80::1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Any help?

Comment: What is netstat -tulpn saying where postgres is listen on?

Comment: netstat: n: unknown or uninstrumented protocol

Comment: Try: `netstat -nlp tcp | grep postgres`. [Source.](http://superuser.com/questions/42843/finding-the-process-that-is-using-a-certain-port-in-linux#comment147205_42846). Are you aware that `localhost` is not a "local" connection type in `pg_haba.conf` on UNIX installations? [More here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15359348/run-batch-file-with-psql-command-without-password/15593100#15593100) Provide settings in your `pg_hba.conf` file, if that does not clear the smoke.

Comment: PostgreSQL probably isn't listening on port 5432, but some other port. Check `port` in `postgresql.conf` or look for listening ports with `netstat` or `lsof`. You're on OS X, which has different tools, so I can't give exact command lines.

Answer (score 1):

Postgresql, just as most databases, can be accessed locally (on the local machine) and on TCP/IP, from remote machines. There is a common phenomenon that a database is configured by default for local connections.

The local connections can happen

- on unix sockets, these are very like TCP ports, but they have a filesystem path instead of a port number. In case of PostgreSQL, the commons settings are 5432 for the TCP port and `/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432`.
- On TCP ports, which is by default `127.0.0.1:5432`, and is often by default turned off.  To turn it on, specify `port = '5432'` in `postgresql.conf`.

Most clients - php postgresql module, or the command line `psql` command - connecting the local server on unix sockets by default.

`pgAdmin` is a special thing, it wants to connect *only* to TCP ports, even if it runs on a localhost. It doesn't mean anything on your system were bad, this tool was simply so written, that it can use only TCP even for localhost administering.

You had to enable the TCP port listening in postgresql config file `pg_hba.conf`. The following line will be probably okay:

```
host all all 127.0.0.0/8 trust
```

The official documentation for this `pg_hba.conf` can you find [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html), and a short tutorial to enable the localhost networking can you find [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/postgres-allow-remote-access-tcp-connection.html).

If it don't work or you want better answer, it could help a lot if you extended your question with your actual `pg_hba.conf`.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Locally, no TCP needed. You need to find the correct Unix domain socket file and call it by adding its path with the "-h" parameter - rather than adding a hostname or IP address.

I found out to get connection to Calendar and Contacts database of El Capitan and Sierra Server.

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8164982

Maybe someone have some experiences with the record structure of the Contacts database?!

Regards from Hamburg